# Ordering Wordpress posts based on parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

UPDATE: I have tried using the following code:

```
<?php if (is_category(events)) { 
$posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=event_date&order=desc'); 
} else {
    $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc'); 
    }
?>
```

Is there any reason why that wouldnt work? It seems to work fine organising posts in alphabetical order, but still no luck on the date order within 'events'.

--

After searching through various existing questions I can't quite find a solution to what I am trying to do.

Currently all posts on my site are ordered alphabetically, which is fine except for one new category that I have added. For this category I want to order all posts by a value that I enter into a custom field. The field is called 'event_date' - so I want to order the posts by date essentially, but not the date the post was created, the date the user manually enters into this field.

I managed to get it working by using:

```
<?php if (is_category($events)) { $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=$event_date&order=asc'); } ?>
```

However this overrides the aphabetical order for all other pages.

For alphabetical order I am using:

```
<?php if (is_category()) { $posts = query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc' ); } ?>
```

Essentially I want a statement that tells the page to order all posts in aphabetical order, unless the category is 'events', where I want to order them by the custom event date.

As you can probably tell I'm very much front end, not back end so a lot of this is fairly new to me, so any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To order posts by a custom field value, you need add the custom meta field to the query itself. `orderby=meta_value` in addition to `meta_key=metafieldid` will allow ordering in this fashion.

I would use the [`pre_get_posts` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and modify the query object if `get_query_var( "cat" )` (or a similar query var) returns the desired post category.

```
add_action( "pre_get_posts", "custom_event_post_order" );

function custom_event_post_order( $query )
{
    $queried_category = $query -> get_query_var( "cat" );

    /*
     * If the query in question is the template's main query and
     * the category ID matches. You can remove the "is_main_query()"
     * check if you need to have every single query overridden on
     * a page (e.g. secondary queries, internal queries, etc.).
     */
    if ( $query -> is_main_query() && $queried_category == 123 )
    {
        $query -> set( "meta_key", "event_date" ); // Your custom field ID.
        $query -> set( "orderby", "meta_value" ); // Or "meta_value_num".
        $query -> set( "order", "ASC" ); // Or "DESC".
    }
}
```

Remember that this approach overrides all queries that are using the category in question. You can build custom WP_Query objects that use their own parameters for constructing loops.

You also should standardize the way you save the custom field data to the database. For dates I prefer using UNIX-timestamp formatted times that are easy to move around and manipulate. This way no accidents happen when querying and some data is formatted in another way that the rest is.

Disclaimer: I did not have the time to test the above code in action, but the general idea should work properly.

EDIT: of course the above code should be inserted to `functions.php` or a similar generic functions file.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood your question, use the `WP_Query` and within the `orderby` add a space between your order by columns:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

if(is_category($events)){
    $args['orderby'] .= " meta_value_num";
    $args['meta_key'] = 'event_date';
}

$posts = (array) new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Would I not need to use an if statement in there somewhere though to tell the events category to display the page differently to other categories?

Comment: Yes you would. Updating answer

Comment: Very much appreciate your help with this, I'm still having no luck using the WP-Query though.

Is there any reason why the following would work correct? It displays all the cateogies in alphabetical order, but not the events in date order?

<?php if (is_category(events)) { 
 $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=event_date&order=desc'); 
} else {
 $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc'); 
 }
?>

Comment: `event_date` is a meta for the post or is it an extra column added to the posts table?

Comment: event_date is one of the custom fields the user has to specify when creating an event post. Thats the value I want to order the posts by, so the closest event in terms of date appears first.

Comment: Understood, but in relation to the physical database schema, does this data get inserted into the meta column, or did it modify the posts table schema? Depending on which, will explain why it's not working.

Comment: Is there any way I can check this to answer your question? It's all a little out of my comfort zone to be honest.

Comment: Do you get your event data from `get_post_meta` or access it from the `$post` object?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I use a plug in to create the custom fields for the category. I do as much front end as I can.

Comment: Try the update. `event_date` for meta_key should be the name of the fireld you want to sort by specifically

Comment: Just to confirm, I just need to stick the code you provided in <?php ?> tags? I have tried it and I get the following error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Query as array in /home/eventssh/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 2800

Comment: Yes, that error is because `$posts` is an object, accessed as `$posts->item` but i changed the code above casting it to an array `(array) new ...`

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<?php $posts = query_posts($query_string . (is_category($events)?'&orderby='.$event_date:'&orderby=title') . '&order=asc');  ?>
```

Comment: I tried using this but then neither display as they should. Appreciate the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$recent = new WP_Query(“cat=ID&showposts=x”);
while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
?>
```